# To get value dynamically in gridview based on button click

Tags: c#, gridview

i have one dropdownlist drpSelectCollege and 2 tables College_M and CollegeSubject_M.In dropdown collegeid is been selected from College_M and now on the basis of College Id another field Subject along with corresponding value of Collegeid is to be displayed in gridview on a click of button search in c#.Plz help me out....

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have a list which you use to bind in the DropDownList.

Look for the `SelectionChanged` event, when the event is fired you can use the `SelectedIndex` to use in your list and get the value you want.